# SchemaUpdate is not updating the schema of the database

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent

The problem I have is that the code below runs but it no longer updates the schema in the database for some reason. Everything else works, I can load and save entities , but everytime I add a new property to one of the entities it does not get added to the db. I have ensured that that I added the properties to the the classMap as well, what have I missed ? (the connectionstring is censored ;) )

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(cs =>
                        cs
                        .Database("qwerty")
                        .Server("qwert")
                        .Password("qwerty")
                        .Username("qwerty")))
                .Mappings(m => 
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true,true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
        }
```

Comment: I know it is not an answer, but we stop using SchemaUpdate in my company because we thought it was not enough reliable.

Comment: Have you checked the database permissions? Have you seen the script `SchemaUpdate` generates? Are you able to run it manually using exactly the same username as in connection string?

Comment: Yes I have no problem with the DB except for this issue. The strange part it created the DB for the first few runs, so it added a few columns but it no longer does that.

Answer (score 3):

Okey, I have solved it.

I had a column that needed to contain a very long text (CLOB) and for some reason when I specified that in the classMap it didn't work, so I changed it manually in the DB.

That is what made nhibernate freak out, so I changed back to the the type that nhibernate selected and everything stared working again!

solution: don't change datatypes in the columns with out permission from nhibernate ;)